# OnScroll Down Header height get but not when Scroll Top

Tags: jquery, css

When I am trying to make when scroll down then header size will reduce but when scroll up so header will make actual size, and when scroll down and header size reduce so content section will reduce `margin-top` but problem is when I do scroll up and `.main` div not get header size and not reducing `margin`. thanks.

```js
$('.main').css('margin-top', ($('.header-outer').height())+'px');
            
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  const scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();

  if (scrollTop  > 1) {
    const mainHeight = $(".header-outer").height();
    $('.main').css('margin-top', mainHeight);
    $('.header-outer').addClass('show');
  } else {
    $('.header-outer').removeClass('show');
    const mainHeight = $(".header-outer").height();
    $('.main').css('margin-top', mainHeight);
    //console.log(mainHeight);
  }
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans:wght@400;500;700&display=swap");

            *,
            *:after,
            *:before {
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            body,html{
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
            }

            body {
                font-family: "DM Sans", sans-serif;
                background-color: #f2f5f7;
                line-height: 1.5;
                min-height: 300vh;
                position: relative;
            }

            .responsive-wrapper {
                width: 90%;
                max-width: 1280px;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
            }

            /* Sticky header */
            .header-outer {
                transition: all .4s ease;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                background-color: #fff;
                box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0, 0.1);
                position: fixed;
                width:100%;
            }
            

            .header-inner {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: space-between;
                padding-top: 100px;
                padding-bottom: 100px;
                transition: all .4s ease;
            }
            .header-outer.show .header-inner{
                padding-top: 30px;
                padding-bottom: 30px;
            }

            /* Styling of other elements */
            .header-logo {
                height: 43px;
            }
            .header-logo img {
                display: block;
            }

            .header-navigation {
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
            }

            .header-navigation a {
                font-size: 1.125rem;
                color: inherit;
                margin-left: 1.75rem;
                position: relative;
                font-weight: 500;
            }

            .header-navigation a {
                display: inline-block;
                font-size: 1.125rem;
                color: inherit;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            .header-navigation a:hover:after {
                transform: scalex(1);
            }

            .header-navigation a:after {
                transition: 0.25s ease;
                content: "";
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                height: 2px;
                background-color: currentcolor;
                transform: scalex(0);
                position: absolute;
                bottom: -2px;
                left: 0;
            }

            .main {
                position:absolute;
                inset: 0;
                transition: all .4s ease;
                padding-top:30px;
            }

            .widget {
                width: 100%;
                max-width: 600px;
                border-radius: 8px;
                box-shadow: 0 15px 30px 0 rgba(0,0,0, 0.1);
                background-color: #fff;
                padding: 2.5rem;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                margin-bottom: 2rem;
                font-size: 1.125rem;
            }

            .widget > * + * {
                margin-top: 1.25em;
            }

            .widget h2 {
                font-size: 1.5rem;
                font-weight: 700;
                line-height: 1.25;
            }

            .widget code {
                display: inline-block;
                padding: 0.125em 0.25em;
                border-radius: 2px;
                background-color: #bee5d3;
            }

            .widget strong {
                font-weight: 700;
            }
            .footer{
                height: 200px;
                background:#000;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Sticky header -->
<header class="header-outer">
  <div class="header-inner responsive-wrapper">
    <div class="header-logo">
      <img src="https://assets.codepen.io/285131/acme-2.svg">
    </div>
    <nav class="header-navigation">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Blog</a>
      <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<!-- Content -->
<main class="main">
  <div class="main-content responsive-wrapper">
    <article class="widget">
      <h2>How does it work without JS? </h2>
      <p>This sticky header consists of two elements: an <strong>outer</strong> and an <strong>inner</strong> container. The outer container is taller than the inner — and the inner is centered vertically.
      </p><p>By utilizing the <code>position: sticky</code> property <strong>twice</strong>, both on the header's <strong>outer container</strong> and <strong>inner container</strong> the outer container will stick to the <code>body</code>, while the inner container will stick to the outer container.</p>
      <p>Note that the outer container has a negative <code>top</code> value equal to the height difference between the two containers. This causes the outer container to stick <strong>above</strong> the <code>body</code>, making the inner container stick to the "ceiling" on scroll.
      </p><p></p>
      <p>This sticky header consists of two elements: an <strong>outer</strong> and an <strong>inner</strong> container. The outer container is taller than the inner — and the inner is centered vertically.
      </p><p>By utilizing the <code>position: sticky</code> property <strong>twice</strong>, both on the header's <strong>outer container</strong> and <strong>inner container</strong> the outer container will stick to the <code>body</code>, while the inner container will stick to the outer container.</p>
      <p>Note that the outer container has a negative <code>top</code> value equal to the height difference between the two containers. This causes the outer container to stick <strong>above</strong> the <code>body</code>, making the inner container stick to the "ceiling" on scroll.
      </p><p></p>
      <p>This sticky header consists of two elements: an <strong>outer</strong> and an <strong>inner</strong> container. The outer container is taller than the inner — and the inner is centered vertically.
      </p><p>By utilizing the <code>position: sticky</code> property <strong>twice</strong>, both on the header's <strong>outer container</strong> and <strong>inner container</strong> the outer container will stick to the <code>body</code>, while the inner container will stick to the outer container.</p>
      <p>Note that the outer container has a negative <code>top</code> value equal to the height difference between the two containers. This causes the outer container to stick <strong>above</strong> the <code>body</code>, making the inner container stick to the "ceiling" on scroll.
      </p><p></p>
      <p>This sticky header consists of two elements: an <strong>outer</strong> and an <strong>inner</strong> container. The outer container is taller than the inner — and the inner is centered vertically.
      </p><p>By utilizing the <code>position: sticky</code> property <strong>twice</strong>, both on the header's <strong>outer container</strong> and <strong>inner container</strong> the outer container will stick to the <code>body</code>, while the inner container will stick to the outer container.</p>
      <p>Note that the outer container has a negative <code>top</code> value equal to the height difference between the two containers. This causes the outer container to stick <strong>above</strong> the <code>body</code>, making the inner container stick to the "ceiling" on scroll.
      </p><p></p>
      <p>This sticky header consists of two elements: an <strong>outer</strong> and an <strong>inner</strong> container. The outer container is taller than the inner — and the inner is centered vertically.
      </p><p>By utilizing the <code>position: sticky</code> property <strong>twice</strong>, both on the header's <strong>outer container</strong> and <strong>inner container</strong> the outer container will stick to the <code>body</code>, while the inner container will stick to the outer container.</p>
      <p>Note that the outer container has a negative <code>top</code> value equal to the height difference between the two containers. This causes the outer container to stick <strong>above</strong> the <code>body</code>, making the inner container stick to the "ceiling" on scroll.
      </p><p></p>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed jQuery code and `body` CSS `min-height: 100vh` only and now it works.

```js
const main            = $('.main');
const header_outer = $('.header-outer');

const initial_height = header_outer.height() + 'px';

main.css('top', initial_height);

$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    const scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();

    if (scrollTop  > 1) {
        header_outer.addClass('show');
        main.css('top', header_outer.height() + "px");
    } else {
        header_outer.removeClass('show');
        main.css('top', initial_height);
    }
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans:wght@400;500;700&display=swap");

            *,
            *:after,
            *:before {
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            body,html{
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
            }

            body {
                font-family: "DM Sans", sans-serif;
                background-color: #f2f5f7;
                line-height: 1.5;
                min-height: 100vh;
                position: relative;
            }

            .responsive-wrapper {
                width: 90%;
                max-width: 1280px;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
            }

            /* Sticky header */
            .header-outer {
                transition: all .4s ease;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                background-color: #fff;
                box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0, 0.1);
                position: fixed;
                width:100%;
        z-index: 1;
            }
            

            .header-inner {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: space-between;
                padding-top: 100px;
                padding-bottom: 100px;
                transition: all .4s ease;
            }
            .header-outer.show .header-inner{
                padding-top: 30px;
                padding-bottom: 30px;
            }

            /* Styling of other elements */
            .header-logo {
                height: 43px;
            }
            .header-logo img {
                display: block;
            }

            .header-navigation {
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
            }

            .header-navigation a {
                font-size: 1.125rem;
                color: inherit;
                margin-left: 1.75rem;
                position: relative;
                font-weight: 500;
            }

            .header-navigation a {
                display: inline-block;
                font-size: 1.125rem;
                color: inherit;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            .header-navigation a:hover:after {
                transform: scalex(1);
            }

            .header-navigation a:after {
                transition: 0.25s ease;
                content: "";
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                height: 2px;
                background-color: currentcolor;
                transform: scalex(0);
                position: absolute;
                bottom: -2px;
                left: 0;
            }

            .main {
                position:relative;
                inset: 0;
                transition: all .4s ease;
                padding-top:30px;
            }

            .widget {
                width: 100%;
                max-width: 600px;
                border-radius: 8px;
                box-shadow: 0 15px 30px 0 rgba(0,0,0, 0.1);
                background-color: #fff;
                padding: 2.5rem;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                margin-bottom: 2rem;
                font-size: 1.125rem;
            }

            .widget > * + * {
                margin-top: 1.25em;
            }

            .widget h2 {
                font-size: 1.5rem;
                font-weight: 700;
                line-height: 1.25;
            }

            .widget code {
                display: inline-block;
                padding: 0.125em 0.25em;
                border-radius: 2px;
                background-color: #bee5d3;
            }

            .widget strong {
                font-weight: 700;
            }
            .footer{
                height: 200px;
                background:#000;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Sticky header -->
        <header class="header-outer">
            <div class="header-inner responsive-wrapper">
                <div class="header-logo">
                    <img src="https://assets.codepen.io/285131/acme-2.svg">
                </div>
                <nav class="header-navigation">
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                    <a href="#">Blog</a>
                    <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- Content -->
        <main class="main">
        
            <div class="main-content responsive-wrapper">
                <article class="widget">
                    <h2>How does it work without JS? </h2>
                    <p>This sticky header consists of two elements: an <strong>outer</strong> and an <strong>inner</strong> container. The outer container is taller than the inner — and the inner is centered vertically.
                    </p><p>By utilizing the <code>position: sticky</code> property <strong>twice</strong>, both on the header's <strong>outer container</strong> and <strong>inner container</strong> the outer container will stick to the <code>body</code>, while the inner container will stick to the outer container.</p>
                    <p>Note that the outer container has a negative <code>top</code> value equal to the height difference between the two containers. This causes the outer container to stick <strong>above</strong> the <code>body</code>, making the inner container stick to the "ceiling" on scroll.
                    </p><p></p>
                    <p>This sticky header consists of two elements: an <strong>outer</strong> and an <strong>inner</strong> container. The outer container is taller than the inner — and the inner is centered vertically.
                    </p><p>By utilizing the <code>position: sticky</code> property <strong>twice</strong>, both on the header's <strong>outer container</strong> and <strong>inner container</strong> the outer container will stick to the <code>body</code>, while the inner container will stick to the outer container.</p>
                    <p>Note that the outer container has a negative <code>top</code> value equal to the height difference between the two containers. This causes the outer container to stick <strong>above</strong> the <code>body</code>, making the inner container stick to the "ceiling" on scroll.
                    </p><p></p>
                    <p>This sticky header consists of two elements: an <strong>outer</strong> and an <strong>inner</strong> container. The outer container is taller than the inner — and the inner is centered vertically.
                    </p><p>By utilizing the <code>position: sticky</code> property <strong>twice</strong>, both on the header's <strong>outer container</strong> and <strong>inner container</strong> the outer container will stick to the <code>body</code>, while the inner container will stick to the outer container.</p>
                    <p>Note that the outer container has a negative <code>top</code> value equal to the height difference between the two containers. This causes the outer container to stick <strong>above</strong> the <code>body</code>, making the inner container stick to the "ceiling" on scroll.
                    </p><p></p>
                    <p>This sticky header consists of two elements: an <strong>outer</strong> and an <strong>inner</strong> container. The outer container is taller than the inner — and the inner is centered vertically.
                    </p><p>By utilizing the <code>position: sticky</code> property <strong>twice</strong>, both on the header's <strong>outer container</strong> and <strong>inner container</strong> the outer container will stick to the <code>body</code>, while the inner container will stick to the outer container.</p>
                    <p>Note that the outer container has a negative <code>top</code> value equal to the height difference between the two containers. This causes the outer container to stick <strong>above</strong> the <code>body</code>, making the inner container stick to the "ceiling" on scroll.
                    </p><p></p>
                    <p>This sticky header consists of two elements: an <strong>outer</strong> and an <strong>inner</strong> container. The outer container is taller than the inner — and the inner is centered vertically.
                    </p><p>By utilizing the <code>position: sticky</code> property <strong>twice</strong>, both on the header's <strong>outer container</strong> and <strong>inner container</strong> the outer container will stick to the <code>body</code>, while the inner container will stick to the outer container.</p>
                    <p>Note that the outer container has a negative <code>top</code> value equal to the height difference between the two containers. This causes the outer container to stick <strong>above</strong> the <code>body</code>, making the inner container stick to the "ceiling" on scroll.
                    </p><p></p>
                </article>
            </div>
            
            <div class="footer"></div>
        </main>
```